# Find files with accented characters unix

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I have some files with french characters (accents like ÂÃÄÀÁÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ).

I am using grep for invidual character.
Is there any easy way to find such files ?

Comment: The characters are in the file or in the filename?

Comment: @fedorqui, They are inside the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sh
grep '[^[:print:]]' FILE
```

Same as

```
[\x20-\x7E]
```

Comment: Thanks @Steven, I helped me to find all accented characters but It also provided some extra lines like Command : $ grep -R '[^[:print:]]' . Output : ./abc.txt: ) ./abc.txt: (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xyz) ./abc.txt: )